# Newbie and don't know where to start with FL Studio

Tags: electronic-music, fl-studio

so Ive been really interested in FL studio and other software such as Reason Propeller-head. I even bought a keyboard piano. My request is for a direction I guess. I don't know where to start. Everytime I open up FL studio, I never end up doing anything. I look for tutorials and then I end up messing around and closing everything.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: Brutal honesty ahead...

If you 'never end up doing anything', how do you think other people can help you?

1. For starters, just start making stuff. It doesn't matter what. I started out with just clicking stuff and responding to the way it sounded. That was 20 years ago..
   I still do that.
2. Define (for yourself) what is 'interesting'. Try to make it sound like an elevator-pitch. "i'm interested in ... because..... this allows me to do....."
3. Be critical after you finished something, not when you start. Or, if you want to make music/sound, don't over-analyse what you do.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you! You have a point. I ended up making stuff in the end and it was good for my expectations. As for what is "interesting", I am inspired by Port blue, Windsor Airlift, ambient music like that, but also by pop music . I just enjoy the emotions these type of sounds can bring up.

Answer (score 0):

You'll always end up doing random stuff, that's just part of the creative process. 99% of the producers have unfinished stuff just hidden away somewhere in their folders.

One of the things I liked to do when I was new to making music (a sub genre of EDM in my case) was fiddling around with the plug-ins, trying to create a sound that I heard somewhere else.

But don't limit yourself, if you end up with something completely different than what you had in mind that's  great too!

For learning purposes, it's wise to check out how tracks in your genre of choice are build, referring to i.e. the length of the intro, what BPM range you should use or what kind of elements a track consists of.

Find a track that you like, and drag it from your folder to the playlist in FL Studio and start analyzing!

Hope this gets you on your way :)

Answer (score 0):

Ever write a paper? How do you do it? Just start writing, right? Same with music. Just start writing. Some songs will be good, others will be sub-par, but in the end you'll have loads of songs to pick from and create an album with.

If you want to know exactly where to start with a song, it's the drum beat. I'm sure you want to know where to start with the drum beat as well. It's the kick and snare. That's it. Once you have a kick and snare pattern, say, 16 bars long, then you can start adding other stuff like keyboard and bass.